# Can't find broadcasted transaction

Tags: etherscan, raw-transaction, sendrawtransaction

I'm trying to broadcast a transaction hex:

```
0xf8a50114830186a094330e4de846f389ec75d1120e3b28c12d270135c880b84403efb5c4000000000000000000000000ad241ff3e63d6b0b5105c8247f99ee8f1b4833300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008ac7230489e800001ca0b5aa20132e4fc28c59ef533f10998a5f2416fb3d8ab187165f43d4d898f21492a0205b96e9fae1b6fe39371246354057ad69f97253c51d3b7dafc47274278321d8
```

Using web3j/infura or etherscan GUI, I get a transaction id:

```
0x0ce1105c3f4768cabcf65dcb32f67087b52bd5d62b786af41890fe012288cb35
```

But this transaction id is never found in any block explorer(etherscan, ethplorer etc).

I'm paying 20 gwei so I don't think the issue is related to the tx fee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gas price is 20 wei, not 20 gwei.

Etherscan will not index transactions with a very low gas price. Try increasing it to 3-5 gwei or so, should be enough to be mined in the next few blocks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. web3j doesn't specify wish unit they use for gasprice so i assumed its gwei